# How to make the transition from Intent to PendingIntent in startActivityAndCollapse() in TileService?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-pendingintent, tile-service

Since Android API 34, `startActivityAndCollapse(Intent intent)` is deprecated, and the official document recommends using `PendingIntent` instead.

Not familiar with PendingIntent, I tried the transition from `Intent` to `PendingIntent`, but some runtime errors came out, and ANR in the app was noticed.

The followings are:

1. the original code using `Intent`.
2. the current code using `PendingIntent` (with runtime errors).
3. the runtime errors shown in the `Logcat` of Android Studio.

How to make the transition right?

1. the original code using `Intent`:

```kotlin
private fun startActivityBasedOnScreenStatus(intent: Intent) {
        if (keyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked) {
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            startActivityAndCollapse(intent)
        }
    }
```

2. the current code using `PendingIntent` (with runtime errors):

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("StartActivityAndCollapseDeprecated")
    private fun startActivityBasedOnScreenStatus(intent: Intent) {
        if (keyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked) {
            startActivity(intent)
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            startActivityAndCollapse(
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    applicationContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
            )
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            startActivityAndCollapse(intent)
        }
    }
```

3. the runtime errors shown in the `Logcat` of Android Studio:

```all
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (1556) for package com.kkhtw.flashlight ----------------------------
2023-12-07 11:46:28.464  1992-2161  WindowManager           system_server                        V      startWCT=WindowContainerTransaction { changes = {} hops = [] errorCallbackToken=null taskFragmentOrganizer=null }
2023-12-07 11:46:28.694  1312-1312  CamX                    and...a.provider@2.7-service-google  E  [ERROR][CHI    ] camxchicontext.cpp:5784 GetSessionData() Did not find any value for the given context key.
2023-12-07 11:46:28.705  1312-1312  CamX                    and...a.provider@2.7-service-google  E  [ERROR][CHI    ] camxchicontext.cpp:5784 GetSessionData() Did not find any value for the given context key.
2023-12-07 11:46:28.889  1556-2968  chromium                com.kkhtw.flashlight                 E  [1207/114628.889465:ERROR:variations_seed_loader.cc(69)] Failed to open file for reading. Errno: 2
2023-12-07 11:46:29.657  1556-3139  Ads                     com.kkhtw.flashlight                 W  Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
2023-12-07 11:46:37.394  1992-3357  ActivityManager         system_server                        E  ANR in com.kkhtw.flashlight (com.kkhtw.flashlight/.MainActivity)
                                                                                                    PID: 1556
                                                                                                    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (5dba712 com.kkhtw.flashlight/com.kkhtw.flashlight.MainActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5002ms for FocusEvent(hasFocus=true))
                                                                                                    Parent: com.kkhtw.flashlight/.MainActivity
                                                                                                    ErrorId: 7c1b5882-3923-4e08-9c0a-ad40f9fe3697
                                                                                                    Frozen: false
                                                                                                    Load: 1.84 / 2.61 / 2.33
                                                                                                    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
                                                                                                    some avg10=0.12 avg60=0.03 avg300=0.02 total=38361876
                                                                                                    full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=10853637
                                                                                                    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
                                                                                                    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/cpu -----
                                                                                                    some avg10=2.17 avg60=1.84 avg300=2.33 total=723752390
                                                                                                    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/cpu -----
                                                                                                    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/io -----
                                                                                                    some avg10=0.01 avg60=0.16 avg300=0.07 total=92657013
                                                                                                    full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.07 avg300=0.02 total=51966787
                                                                                                    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/io -----
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    CPU usage from 46486ms to -1ms ago (2023-12-07 11:45:48.343 to 2023-12-07 11:46:34.830):
                                                                                                      73% 2023/com.cathay.mymobione:xdvdydzdudodkdqdeiyizioikijiqixezeuekeqedwiwewxwhwpwvwywzwlwowtwgwjwqwxsys:wd: 73% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 35924 minor
                                                                                                      5% 1556/com.kkhtw.flashlight: 4.7% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 43419 minor 1 major
                                                                                                      11% 1992/system_server: 7.6% user + 3.7% kernel / faults: 16091 minor 8 major
                                                                                                      4.9% 2881/com.android.systemui: 3.7% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 6532 minor 9 major
                                                                                                      4.7% 659/surfaceflinger: 3% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 130 minor 2 major
                                                                                                      2.9% 3378/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 2.2% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 6523 minor 20 major
                                                                                                      2.8% 519/crtc_event:105: 0% user + 2.8% kernel
                                                                                                      2.7% 661/vendor.qti.hardware.display.composer-service: 1.8% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 1209 minor
                                                                                                      1.5% 29452/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher: 1.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 1528 minor
                                                                                                      0.5% 1309/android.hardware.audio.service: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 14 minor 24 major
                                                                                                    19% TOTAL: 15% user + 3.3% kernel + 0% iowait + 0.6% irq + 0.1% softirq
                                                                                                    CPU usage from 67ms to 650ms later (2023-12-07 11:46:34.896 to 2023-12-07 11:46:35.479):
                                                                                                      197% 1556/com.kkhtw.flashlight: 193% user + 4.4% kernel / faults: 1046 minor
                                                                                                        101% 1556/khtw.flashlight: 96% user + 4.4% kernel
                                                                                                        94% 1569/ReferenceQueueD: 94% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                        6.7% 1567/HeapTaskDaemon: 4.4% user + 2.2% kernel
                                                                                                      140% 1992/system_server: 71% user + 69% kernel / faults: 6223 minor
                                                                                                        78% 2045/Signal Catcher: 55% user + 23% kernel
                                                                                                        52% 3358/AnrAuxiliaryTas: 13% user + 39% kernel
                                                                                                        4.6% 2671/SensorService: 2.3% user + 2.3% kernel
                                                                                                        2.3% 2707/ackgroundThread: 0% user + 2.3% kernel
                                                                                                        2.3% 4931/binder:1992_13: 2.3% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      100% 2023/com.cathay.mymobione:xdvdydzdudodkdqdeiyizioikijiqixezeuekeqedwiwewxwhwpwvwywzwlwowtwgwjwqwxsys:wd: 100% user + 0% kernel / faults: 35 minor
                                                                                                        100% 2110/Thread-10: 100% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                       +0% 3368/Timer-35: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      19% 4738/com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.zhuyin: 17% user + 2.4% kernel / faults: 1235 minor
                                                                                                        19% 4749/Signal Catcher: 17% user + 2.4% kernel
                                                                                                      1.7% 72/rcuop/7: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
                                                                                                      2.2% 1331/android.hardware.sensors@2.0-service.multihal: 0% user + 2.2% kernel
                                                                                                        2.2% 2643/sensors@2.0-ser: 0% user + 2.2% kernel
                                                                                                      2.4% 3993/irq/44-90cd000.: 0% user + 2.4% kernel
                                                                                                      3.1% 13043/adbd: 3.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                        3.1% 13043/adbd: 3.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      3.5% 27139/kworker/u16:10-kverityd: 0% user + 3.5% kernel
                                                                                                    57% TOTAL: 45% user + 10% kernel + 0.8% irq
2023-12-07 11:46:38.715  9866-1196  SQLiteDatabase          com.google.android.apps.turbo        E  Error inserting timezone=Asia/Taipei timestamp_millis=1701920748000 battery_level=95 battery_saver=2 charge_type=0 place_key=null
                                                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: battery_event.timestamp_millis (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:961)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:89)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1870)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1739)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.turbo.nudges.broadcasts.BatteryHistoryLoggerJobService.f(PG:164)
                                                                                                        at avc.accept(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1528)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.turbo.nudges.broadcasts.BatteryHistoryLoggerJobService.d(PG:37)
                                                                                                        at aty.run(PG:65)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
                                                                                                        at dor.a(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at doa.run(PG:4)
                                                                                                        at dos.run(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2023-12-07 11:46:38.717  9866-1196  SQLiteDatabase          com.google.android.apps.turbo        E  Error inserting timezone=Asia/Taipei timestamp_millis=1701920748000 battery_level=95 battery_saver=2 charge_type=2 place_key=null
                                                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: battery_event.timestamp_millis (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:961)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:89)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1870)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1739)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.turbo.nudges.broadcasts.BatteryHistoryLoggerJobService.f(PG:164)
                                                                                                        at avc.accept(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1528)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.turbo.nudges.broadcasts.BatteryHistoryLoggerJobService.d(PG:37)
                                                                                                        at aty.run(PG:65)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
                                                                                                        at dor.a(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at doa.run(PG:4)
                                                                                                        at dos.run(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2023-12-07 11:46:49.164  1992-3419  ActivityManager         system_server                        I  Skipping duplicate ANR: com.android.server.am.ProcessErrorStateRecord@edbe253 executing service com.kkhtw.flashlight/.MyTileService
2023-12-07 11:47:10.843  1312-1312  CamX                    and...a.provider@2.7-service-google  E  [ERROR][CHI    ] camxchicontext.cpp:5784 GetSessionData() Did not find any value for the given context key.
2023-12-07 11:47:10.849  1312-1312  CamX                    and...a.provider@2.7-service-google  E  [ERROR][CHI    ] camxchicontext.cpp:5784 GetSessionData() Did not find any value for the given context key.
2023-12-07 11:47:11.003  1312-1312  CamX                    and...a.provider@2.7-service-google  E  [ERROR][CHI    ] camxchicontext.cpp:5784 GetSessionData() Did not find any value for the given context key.
2023-12-07 11:47:11.008  1312-1312  CamX                    and...a.provider@2.7-service-google  E  [ERROR][CHI    ] camxchicontext.cpp:5784 GetSessionData() Did not find any value for the given context key.
```

Comment: Your `MainActivity` is doing too much work on the main thread and causing an ANR. That has nothing to do with your TileService.

Comment: But before the the deprecation of `startActivityAndCollapse(Intent intent)` in API 34, the app runs well and has been published on Google Play, with no ANRs in the Play Console.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a different problem. The problem is probably that you have something that is causing an infinite loop on Android 14, which is causing the ANR. I don't think it has anything to do with the changes to `startActivityAndCollapse()`. The method was deprecated in API 34, but not removed. So you can still use it. You should go back to your old code and see how it behaves on a device running API 34. I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidWasser I agree. After several days of trying, I'm guessing that the issue comes from `SensorManager.registerListener()` for `ROTATION_VECTOR`, `ACCELEROMETER`, or `MAGNETIC_FIELD`, though still haven't figured it out. Thank you :)

Comment: See if you can use some debug tools to get a thread dump when the ANR occurs. You need to see where the infinite loop is.